# saving any file with VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to save any file with VBA code?

Speciffically I a trying to save an already existing PDF file to a different lacation. The macro is run within excel workbook.

I have been  browsing net for the answer, yet resultlessly, maybe I am asking wrong questions.

I would appreciate any help, pointing to tge right  "key words" would be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be so many options for you FileCopy, Move, Name etc. are a few.

However, Ron De Bruin, has a great article on this, http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm